# Skip error urls android

Tags: android

How can i get a new Image when the URL does noe exist.

here is my activity code:

package com.ddd.funnic.TouchView;

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.ImageView.ScaleType;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

import com.ddd.R;
import com.ddd.TouchView.InputStreamWrapper.InputStreamProgressListener;


public class UrlTouchImageView extends RelativeLayout {
    protected ProgressBar mProgressBar;
    protected TouchImageView mImageView = null;

    protected Context mContext;


    public UrlTouchImageView(Context ctx)
    {
        super(ctx);
        mContext = ctx;
        init();

    }
    public UrlTouchImageView(Context ctx, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(ctx, attrs);
        mContext = ctx;
        init();
    }
    public TouchImageView getImageView() { return mImageView; }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    protected void init() {
        mImageView = new TouchImageView(mContext);
        LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
        mImageView.setLayoutParams(params);
        this.addView(mImageView);
        mImageView.setVisibility(GONE);

        mProgressBar = new ProgressBar(mContext, null, android.R.attr.progressBarStyleHorizontal);
        params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL);
        params.setMargins(30, 0, 30, 0);
        mProgressBar.setLayoutParams(params);
        mProgressBar.setIndeterminate(false);
        mProgressBar.setMax(100);
        this.addView(mProgressBar);
    }

    public void setUrl(String imageUrl)
    {
        new ImageLoadTask().execute(imageUrl);
    }
    //No caching load
    public class ImageLoadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Bitmap>
    {
        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... strings) {
            String url = strings[0];
            Bitmap bm = null;
            try {
                URL aURL = new URL(url);
                URLConnection conn = aURL.openConnection();
                conn.connect();
                InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
                int totalLen = conn.getContentLength();
                InputStreamWrapper bis = new InputStreamWrapper(is, 8192, totalLen);
                bis.setProgressListener(new InputStreamProgressListener()
                {                   
                    @Override
                    public void onProgress(float progressValue, long bytesLoaded,
                            long bytesTotal)
                    {
                        publishProgress((int)(progressValue * 100));
                    }
                });
                bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bis);
                bis.close();
                is.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return bm;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute (Bitmap bitmap) {
            if (bitmap == null)  
            {

                mImageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER);
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.no_photo);
                mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            }


            if(bitmap != null)
            {

                mImageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);
                mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            }

            mImageView.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
            mProgressBar.setVisibility(GONE);

            }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values)
        {
            mProgressBar.setProgress(values[0]);
        }



        }

        }
```

I want to get a new Url to load another Picture if it is **Bitmap == null**.

please help me it is very important.

Answer (score 0):

In your `ImageLoadTask` you open a `URLConnection`. If that connection does not exist, an exception will be thrown and the code in the `catch` clause will execute. You can `return` a default bitmap in the `catch` clause.

```
public class ImageLoadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Bitmap>
{
    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... strings) {
        String url = strings[0];
        Bitmap bm = null;
        try {
        ...
        ...
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            // add this line
            bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.no_photo); // <---------------
        }
        return bm;
    }
    ...
    ...
}
```

Comment: Okey
i am a beginner please can you text me what i have to write in it i dont know how to make this.

Thanke you for the first.

Comment: Yes
but i want to get another URL or get the next URL from the Gallery and not the photo which is Show when it is no Image.